# Cannot submit form with capybara, GET instead of POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, capybara

I run in a very strange problem. I'm writing some specs for my Rails 3.2.18 application and I found out that my forms are not submitted and all the tests are failing.

I'm using

- Rails 3.2.18
- Rspec 2.13.0
- Capybara 2.3.0
- Poltergeist 1.5.1

This is a (stripped) down example of my login form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: { id: 'new_user_session' }) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :redirect_to, URI(params[:redirect_to] || request.referer || request.env['PATH_INFO']).path %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: 1 } %>
  <%= f.submit t('sign_in') %>
<% end %>
```

And this is the feature spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Sign in' do

  before do
    @user = create(:user, email: 'user@example.com', password: 'supersecret', password_confirmation: 'supersecret')
    @user.confirm!
  end

  scenario 'a registered user' do
    visit '/home'

    expect(page).to     have_content I18n.t('sign_in')
    expect(page).not_to have_content I18n.t('profile')

    click_link I18n.t('sign_in')

    expect(current_path).to eq('/users/sign_in')

    expect(find('#redirect_to').value).to eq('/home')

    within '#new_user_session' do
      fill_in 'user_email',    with: 'user@example.com'
      fill_in 'user_password', with: 'supersecret'

      click_button I18n.t('sign_in')
    end

    expect(current_path).to eq('/home')

    expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t('devise.sessions.signed_in'))

    expect(page).not_to have_content I18n.t('sign_in')
    expect(page).to     have_content I18n.t('profile')
  end

end
```

The test is failing because after apparently filling the form and clicking on the button, the current_path is not the one expected (I should be redirected to the home).

In the logs I can see that the form is non submitted with a POST request but with a GET (this is the second one after the initial visit to the login page):

```
Completed 200 OK in 164.1ms (Views: 161.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-22 23:25:23 +0200
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
```

The funny thing is that if I copy and paste the HTML code from the rendered page and put it in the partial instead of the simple_form helpers it works and the test passes with the correct POST request! I used form_for and form_tag as well and it doesn't work either. This is the generated code:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" class="simple_form new_user" id="new_user_session" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="f8SGSa4y8l9imeaa9oJtsT0JShPw2NEaYOKfA/9IL0O0=" /></div>
  <input id="redirect_to" name="redirect_to" type="hidden" value="/users/sign_in" />
  <div class="input email optional user_email field_with_hint"><label class="email optional" for="user_email">Email</label><input class="string email optional" id="user_email" maxlength="255" name="user[email]" size="50" type="email" value="" /><span class="hint">Email</span></div>
  <div class="input password optional user_password field_with_hint"><label class="password optional" for="user_password">Password</label><input class="password optional" id="user_password" maxlength="128" name="user[password]" size="50" type="password" /><span class="hint">Password</span></div>
  <div class="input hidden user_remember_me"><input class="hidden" id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="1" /></div>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

I can test this features (sign up, reset password and confirm) in different ways but I want to understand what's wrong with my code.

EDIT: This is the failure message from Rspec. I guess it doesn't help that much, basically it fails at the check if the current_path is the one provided with the redirect_to:

```
F

Failures:

  1) Sign in a registered user
     Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq('/home')

       expected: "/home"
            got: "/users/sign_in"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/features/signin_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.09 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/signin_spec.rb:10 # Sign in a registered user
```

It should be /home (devise redirect to the params[:redirect_to]) but it's /users/sign_in since the form is not submitted with a POST but it's a GET to the same path (so the form is only re-rendered).

UPDATED: I solved the issue by upgrading the gem versions to the latest one.

- Rails 3.2.21
- Rspec 3.1.0
- Capybara 2.4.4
- Poltergeist 1.5.1

Comment: Can you post the error message that you receive when your rspec example fails.

Comment: I added the failure message in the original text.

Comment: I actually solved this issue by upgrading to the latest version of the gems listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by upgrading the gem versions to the latest one.

- Rails 3.2.21
- Rspec 3.1.0
- Capybara 2.4.4
- Poltergeist 1.5.1

The problem was solved and my specs are passing now.